# Connecting to SQL Server with HeidiSQL

Tags: sql-server, heidisql

I am using Windows 10 64bit. I installed SQL Server 2014 Express. The SQL Server service is running. Now I am trying to connect to the running SQL Server with HeidiSQL. I am using SQL Server named pipes and it is not working. Can you please help me about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed with all defaults, then the server/instance name to use for SQL Server Express would be:

- `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`
- `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`
- `YourPcNameHere\SQLEXPRESS`

Either of those should work just fine